# how to use xsl to change name child node

Tags: xml

how to use xsl to change name of child node if it = to the parent node and apply to all nodes

example

```
< items >
< items >3</items >
</items >
```

to

```
< items >
< parentname-"inner"childname >3</parentname-"inner"childname >
</items >
```

thank you very much

Comment: Neither of the above snips are valid XML, the "to" target is badly wrong.  Please could you fix this to be valid XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, and you want to generate the following XML from your sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<items>
<items-items>3</items-items>
</items>
```

then **the following XSLT can be used**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--Match elements who's name is equal to it's parent -->
<xsl:template match="*[name()=name(..)]">
    <!--create an element using the name of the parent element, followed by a "-", followed by the matched element name -->
    <xsl:element name="{name(..)}-{name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```